# GridLayout vs. RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I am just starting with Android development and there are at least two ways to build a grid: using [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout) or using a RecyclerView with a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager).

- Is there any case/reason still to use a GridLayout?
- Is it maybe faster at rendering/loading, as it maybe is simpler?

I want to build a grid of cards, likely around max. 50 cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to just use GridLayout if you don't need the functionality of the RecyclerView. Nevertheless, you should get involved with the RecyclerView asap(it's a very strong tool).

Up to a certain size, the solo GridLayout will render/load faster but at some point, this effect will reverse:

> Recycle (view): A view previously used to display data for a specific adapter position may be placed in a cache for later reuse to display the same type of data again later. This can drastically improve performance by skipping initial layout inflation or construction.

Comment: plus it needs less memory, because of viewholder's pool

Comment: thank you guys! After reading up further I decided to always use RecyclerView. It's nice to use and if you amount of data grows one won't have issues :-)